# Updating $scope variable from ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `ngRepeat` loop in a view and for every item I have a custom toggle control connected to a `$scope` variable like this:

```
<a ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="isOn = !isOn" ng-class="{on: isOn}">
   Toggle!
</a>
```

When a link is clicked the `isO`n variable is toggled as expected, but **only for the item clicked**. I would expect all items are updated as isOn is defined in controller as `$scope.isOn = false`

When I toggle the variable using controller method **all** items are updated!

```
<a ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="toggle()" ng-class="{on: isOn}">
   Toggle!
</a>

--- controller ---

$scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.isOn = !$scope.isOn;
}
```

Can you explain this behaviour? Is it because ngRepeat is creating a separate scope for every item?

Comment: try `$scope.$apply()` in toggle function after you set isOn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `ngRepeat` is creating a separate scope for every item. See [AngularJS ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. Each template instance gets its own scope...

**Edit:** from @doodeec comment

You could toggle a parent scope instead.
`ng-click="$parent.isOn = !$parent.isOn"`

Comment: and the simplest solution is to use ng-click="$parent.isOn = !$parent.isOn"

Comment: You are right, but I would prefer ng-click="toggle()" insead of ng-click="$parent.isOn = !$parent.isOn"